# How to extract part of URL between two different characters with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have url that has a following structure:

```
https://example.com/string?rest
```

I am trying to extract only the 'string' part and so far I can only think of using

```
response.url.split('/')[3]
```

to extract everything after third '/'
Is it possible to extract the part after third '/' and before the '?' sign?

Answer (score 2):

Might be able to use something in `urllib.parse`:

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse
print(urlparse(response.url).path.split('/')[-1])
```